# Count Totals by Day of Week and Week Total for each Subject

Tags: mysql

In my table I have recorded various bits of information but the key fields for this problem are the subject_id and lesson_time where I want to group by subject to give a total count of rows for each day of week for each subject and total rows for each subject(weekly total), so from this sample data:

```
id    subject_id   lesson_time
1        4         2015-04-28
2        4         2015-04-28
3        3         2015-04-28
4        1         2015-04-28
5        4         2015-04-27
```

I want to count the totals for each subject for monday to friday and week total, so output for the above data example would be:

```
subject_id    monday_total   tuesday_total   wednesday_total  ... week_total
  1               0                1               0                  1
  3               0                1               0                  1
  4               1                2               0                  3
```

I can get total by subject easy enough as it is just count(*) after group by, what I am struggling with is the count for each individual day, my current (non working) query is

```
SELECT
    subject_id,
    COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2) AS monday_total,
    COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=3) AS tuesday_total,
    COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=4) AS wednesday_total,
    COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=5) AS thursday_total,
    COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=6) AS friday_total,
    COUNT(*) AS week_total
FROM
    tbl_lessons
GROUP BY
    subject_id
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: change `COUNT( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2)` to `SUM( DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2)`

Comment: Do you want to include Saturday and Sunday in your `GROUP BY` total?

Comment: @Aelfwine that's nice. please accept my answer below

Comment: @Peter - your answer was spot on but it won't let me accept yet, says I have to wait a few minutes but will do as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
    subject_id,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2) AS monday_total,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=3) AS tuesday_total,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=4) AS wednesday_total,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=5) AS thursday_total,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=6) AS friday_total,
    COUNT(*) AS week_total
FROM
    tbl_lessons
GROUP BY
    subject_id
```

In mysql `COUNT(n)` counts every row (+ 1 for every row where `n` is not `NULL`). `SUM(n)` sums all `n` values (+ `n` for every row).

As boolean expression returns 1 or 0 `SUM(DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2)` will return number of rows where `DAYOFWEEK(lesson_time)=2` (it's like summing booleans 1+0+0+1+1+1+0+0+1+...)

Comment: @fancyPants in my opinion this is really trivial question, idk is explanation really necessary I could only add link to mysql manual. But probably you are right, feel free to add another answer with full explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT date(lesson_time) AS lesson_time, count( * ) AS count FROM tbl_lessons GROUP BY date(lesson_time)
```